# SQL Server, Select statement inside a 'case'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone help me with the right syntax in SQL Server, I have something that looks like this inside a larger query

```
VSCS.ISCOTEACH,
VSCS.NoMARKS,
CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_CoTeacher COTH WHERE    COTH.CLAS_METG_TIME_PK=VSCS.CLAS_METG_TIME_PK
        AND ISNULL(COTH.DELT_FLAG,0)=0) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HASCOTEACH),
```

The third line on is not correct of course, pretty much I want a column called `HASCOTEACH` to contain a 1 if the query  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_CoTeacher COTH WHERE COTH.CLAS_METG_TIME_PK=VSCS.CLAS_METG_TIME_PK AND ISNULL(COTH.DELT_FLAG,0)=0` returns a value greater than 1, 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try like this..

```
(CASE when (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_CoTeacher COTH WHERE    COTH.CLAS_METG_TIME_PK=VSCS.CLAS_METG_TIME_PK
        AND ISNULL(COTH.DELT_FLAG,0)=0) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HASCOTEACH
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like following :

```
VSCS.ISCOTEACH,
VSCS.NoMARKS,
CASE WHEN 
      (
       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_CoTeacher COTH WHERE COTH.CLAS_METG_TIME_PK=VSCS.CLAS_METG_TIME_PK
       AND ISNULL(COTH.DELT_FLAG,0)=0
       ) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HASCOTEACH,
```